# Index of the node selected not based on his parent

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an xml like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<root>
    <something>
       <cd>a1</cd>
       <cd>a2</cd>
    </something>
    <another>
       <cd>b1</cd>
       <cd>b2</cd>
       <cd>b3</cd>
       <cd>b1</cd>
       <cd>b2</cd>
       <cd>b3</cd>
       <cd>b1</cd>
       <cd>b2</cd>       
    </another>
</root>
```

I'm selecting all the cd nodes and trying to take the cds from 10 to 10 (1st, 11th, 21th...) this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <html><body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//cd" />
       </body></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd"/>

    <xsl:template match="cd[position() mod 10 = 1]">
        <div>
            pos:<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>;
            value:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output:

```
 pos:1; value:a1
pos:3; value:b3
```

And the expected output:

```
pos:1; value:a1
pos:11; value:b11
```

The problem is that `position()` **in the match** is the node number based on his parent. So the `position()` of "b1" is 1 and not 3. Is there a function to know the index of the current node?

Thanks in advance.

//EDIT to extend the example

Comment: Can you explain what "And I'm trying to take the cds from 10 to 10 this way" means? Are you trying to display the first 10 `cd`s?

Comment: You can set a variable containing all CDs `<xsl:variable name="all-cds" select="//cd" />` and then loop through them `<xsl:for-each select="$all-cds">` and you will get their position independent of their parents.

Comment: @DanielHaley I want the 1st element, the 11th, the 21th, etc. I've just edited the question to extend the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a more accurate count by using `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <div>pos: <xsl:number level="any"/></div>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also count the preceding `cd` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <div>pos: <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::cd)+1"/></div>
</xsl:template>
```

I prefer `xsl:number`, but I suppose it depends on how you're using the value. If you give a better example of what you're trying to do with that number, I can update my answer.

Example based on question update:

**Input**

```
<root>
    <something>
        <cd>a1</cd>
        <cd>a2</cd>
    </something>
    <another>
        <cd>b1</cd>
        <cd>b2</cd>
        <cd>b3</cd>
        <cd>b1</cd>
        <cd>b2</cd>
        <cd>b3</cd>
        <cd>b1</cd>
        <cd>b2</cd>       
    </another>
    <another>
        <cd>c1</cd>
        <cd>c2</cd>
        <cd>c3</cd>
        <cd>c1</cd>
        <cd>c2</cd>
        <cd>c3</cd>
        <cd>c1</cd>
        <cd>c2</cd>       
    </another>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html><body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//cd" />
        </body></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd"/>

    <xsl:template match="cd[(count(preceding::cd)+1) mod 10 = 1]">
        <div>
            pos:<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>;
            value:<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         pos:1;
         value:a1
      </div>
      <div>
         pos:11;
         value:c1
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but in the template match the position is refering to his parents and I want it to be the index of the selection

Comment: @MazarD - Huh? Don't use `position()` at all. See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 2):

The position() in the match of template filters "cd"s based on position in its parent:

```
<xsl:template match="cd[position() mod (10) = 1]">
```

and the position() inside the template definition,

```
<div>pos:<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></div>
```

gives you the cd's sequence which the template has been applied for.

Thus, "position() mod (10) = 1" filters only those "cd"s which are 1st, 11th, 21st, etc. children of their parents.

Hence, you can remove the filter from xsl:template's match and put it inside like this:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
    <div>pos:<xsl:if test="position() mod 10 = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will save all the CDs in a variable. In the `for-each`, the context does not depend on the parent nodes so you will get the position among all CDs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="all-cds" select="//cd" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="$all-cds">
            <div>pos: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I finally used the xsl:if to test the position instead of the template match, but your solution is great, thank you, I will surely use it in the future.